# Hard combinatorics and probability question.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

A large white cube is painted red, and then cut into $27$ identical smaller cubes. These smaller cubes are shuffled randomly.

A blind man (who also cannot feel the paint) reassembles the small cubes into a large one. What is the probability that the outside of this large cube is completely red?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Hint: Try to find first the probability that the corner cubes are put into the corners, the face cubes into the faces and the edge cubes into the edges. Then the probability that they have the correct orientation.

**Complete answer:**

First, number the small cubes to make them distinguishable.

Without taking into account the orientation of the smaller cubes, there are 27! possible ways to reassemble them into a big cube.

- There is 1 way to place the center cube correctly
- There are 6! ways to place the face cubes correctly
- There are 8! ways to place the corner cubes correctly
- There are 12! ways to place the edge cubes correctly

So there are 6!8!12! correct cubes (without taking into account the orientation).

Now take such a cube.

- The center cube has probability 1 of being in the correct orientation.
- Each face cube has probability 1/6 of being in the correct orientation.
- Each corner cube has probability 1/8 of being in the correct orientation.
- Each edge cube has probability 1/12 of being in the correct orientation.

This means that the probability of getting a red cube must be

$$\frac{6!8!12!}{27!}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^6\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^8\left(\frac{1}{12}\right)^{12}$$

Comment: That's a little less than one chance in $2\times 10^{35}$, if my calculator was behaving.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Close. It's one chance in $\approx 5.465\times 10^{36}$ ([Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%286%218%2112%21%29%2F%2827%21%29*%281%2F6%29%5E6%281%2F8%29%5E8%281%2F12%29%5E12)).

Comment: I think you're forgetting the fact that each sub-cube can be rotated and placed in $144$ different ways. In order to place them correctly, the ones in the corners have only $1$ legal rotation. The ones on the sides have $2$ legal rotations. The ones on the center of each face have $6$ legal rotations. The one in the center has $144$ legal rotations.

Comment: Although some of these rotations yield "so called" identical cubes, in terms of probability, the blind man can still reassemble each one of these identical versions, and so they need to be accounted for when computing the probability.

Comment: @barakmanos: No, you are wrong and this answer is right. To begin with, there are only $24$ orientation-preserving symmetries of a cube, not $144$. And for a corner cube there are $3$ of them that will produce the correct colouring (rotation about the axis passing through the corner is OK). And so forth.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: For counting **different** variations of the cube you are correct. But for calculating probability, I think that one needs to account for **identical** (symmetric) versions of the cube as if they were different.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: I used a simpler way to compute the probability to get the small cube in the correct orientation : for the face cube, you can only interest you in face, hence 1/6. The rotations doesn't change the facts that only one face will be outside, and that each face is equiprobable. Same with the edge : there is 12 edges, and they are all equiprobable to be on the edge of the cube. And for the corner, there is 8 corners and all are equiprobable to be on the corner off the cube. Hence the result

Comment: @barakmanos: I don't follow. I don't see what it means to have more than one identical (not just indistinguishable) configuration, nor what reason there could be to count the _same_ configuration multiple times (and if so, how many times?), nor what kind of counting of symmetries of a cube could have $144$ as answer. Maybe you could start explaining that last point.

Comment: @Tryss: Yes, I know, that's what I would do too. But I was trying to explain to barakmanos that even using the full set of symmetries leads to the same answer.

Comment: @barakmanos: I think it might be easier to view the cubes as number and the possible cube slots numbered as well. This fixes the cube orientation and now you don't need to worry about symmetries because you don't care about which numbers each placed cube has, just its type.