# Probability & cube problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A $3\times3$ cube made up of $1\times1$ pieces is painted red from all faces and broken in $27$ smaller pieces ($1\times1$). A Blind man comes and randomly arranges pieces to make a $3\times3$ cube. What is the probability that a cube similar to the original is formed (red faces from all sides)?

Comment: Interesting problem! What are your thoughts on the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Let's count the number of ways that this can happen, and then divide by the total number of permutations.

There are four types of pieces: center piece (with no colored sides), middle pieces (with one colored side), edge pieces, with two colored sides, and corner pieces with three colored sides.

Each type of piece must be moved to another piece with the same type.

The middle piece must be placed in the middle with any of the $24$ orientations.

For center pieces, there are $6$ of them, so there are $6!$ permutations of the pieces, but there are $4$ valid orientations for each, so there are $4^6\cdot6!$ valid reorderings.

For edge pieces, of which there are $12$, there are $12!$ permutations of the pieces, but each one has $2$ valid orientations, making $2^{12}\cdot12!$ valid reorderings.

For corner pieces, of which there are $8$, there are $8!$ permutations, but there are $3$ valid orientations, making $3^8\cdot8!$ valid reorderings.

In total, there are $24^{27}\cdot27!$ possible ways for the blind man to mess around with the blocks, so our answer is

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{24\cdot4^6\cdot6!\cdot2^{12}\cdot12!\cdot3^8\cdot8!}{24^{27}\cdot27!}&=\frac{6!\cdot12!\cdot8!}{6^6\cdot12^{12}\cdot8^8\cdot27!}\\
&=\frac{1}{5,465,062,811,999,459,151,238,583,897,240,371,200}
\end{aligned}$$
The probability is approximately $1.8\times10^{-37}$.

Comment: For the center pieces, there are $4^6\cdot6!$ valid orderings, and similarly for the edges, corners, and in the denominator. This question is, however, a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1939512/3736), and I've voted to close.

Comment: @WillOrrick I voted to close as well. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: There still seem to be some things missing.  Shouldn't the total (in the line just before the displayed equation) be $24^{27}\cdot27!$ rather than $6\cdot27!$? This would need to be corrected in the displayed equation itself too.. Also, the expressions to the right of the equals signs in the displayed equation don't seem to agree with the expression to the left of the first equals sign, although numerical value in the next line appears to be the right order of magnitude.

Comment: @WillOrrick Yea, there were so many things wrong that I just gave up trying to fix it.

Comment: Since this question may stick around, even though closed, I though it best to make sure the answer was correct, so I've made the changes.

Comment: @WillOrrick Thank you!